# how to write below code componentdidmount code in useeffect?

Tags: react-native

```
class CategoriesProductsScreen extends Component {
    
      state = {
        filteredProducts : [],
         count : -12
      }
```

how to write component did mount code in use effect in functional component>?

componentDidMount = ()=>{

```
 let category = this.props.navigation.getParam("title");
let products = this.props.products.products.filter(
  (product)=>{
    return product.category == category
  }
);

this.setState({
  filteredProducts : products,
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const CategoriesProductsScreen  = (props) =>{

  const [filterProducts, setFilterProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{

    let category = props.navigation.getParam("title");
    let products = props.products.products.filter(
        (product)=>{
          return product.category == category
        }
      );
      setFilterProducts(products)
  },[])
```

}

Comment: Writing like this says invalid hook call

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use useEffect and React functional components, you'll have to substitute state management with something like the useState hook as well.

Your component will look something like:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const CategoriesProductsScreen = (props) => {
const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);
const [count, setCount] = useState(-12);

useEffect(() => {
const category = props.navigation.getParam("title");
const products = props.products.products.filter(
  (product)=>{
    return product.category === category
  }
);

setFilteredProducts(products)
}) // you can also add an empty dependency array

return (
/* whatever you want the component to return/render */
)
}
```